# Does conjoining two questions count as an "erotetic inference"?

Tags: logic, inference

For example:

1. Why is an eagle like a microscope?
2. Who doesn't go here?
3. "Therefore," why is an eagle like a microscope and who doesn't go here?

Part of why I'm unsure about this being an "inference" is that I have some doubts about **conjunction itself** being inference-theoretic in the required way. Like, if I make two assertions in a row, in communication-time, I have some trouble seeing how putting an "and" between those assertions makes any difference or converts the two statements into one.

Another counterpoint example:

4. Have you stopped kissing the Sword of the Walnut God?
5. [Disjunction introduction?] Therefore, have you stopped kissing the SWG or is the moon made of extremely dense parmesan?

Or what about:

6. Why am I obsessed with coconut crabs?
7. [Double-negation introduction] Therefore, why am I not not obsessed with coconut crabs? Or: Not not why am I obsessed with coconut crabs? (What in the blazes does that even mean...!)

Comment: I would be inclined to say, yes, but what of it? The converse would qualify, i.e. splitting up a complex question into a several simpler ones. That is usually a more useful way to proceed. But nobody said logic always has to be useful or relevant.

Comment: @Bumble, I do think there are inferences or maybe "quasi-inferences" from questions to answers, as if an answer could be inferred from the very question (this is what I take for analytic apriority, for now). And maybe some answers yield questions, and some questions do yield other questions, too. However, I wonder if these relations end up being more "mathematical"? Some erotetic-sounding remark of Cantor's (I'll try to find it) is weighing on my mind, among other things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called relevance logic which only allows expressions to be connected by a logical operator like and iff the two expressions are relevant to each other. Formally, this is done in relevance logic if and only if the two expressions share a nonlogical constant.

Since 1 & 2 do not share a non-logical constant, then relevance logic will say that you are pointlessly conjoining irrelevant information for the purposes of inference.

Comment: Something like this is what I expected (that erotetics would gravitate towards relevance logic). It's sort of funny, this paraconsistency guy Zach Weber said that a professor of his (not Priest, I think) told him that "relevance logic was the key to the universe," a claim I wouldn't have been of a mind to agree with much until just this last week...